# flattening a json column to multiple columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like the following format

```
   email          name    permissions
  abc@gmail.com   abc    {'system_role': {'title': 'uadmin', 'mask': 64.0}, 'account_roles': [{'role': {'title': 'user', 'mask': 4}}], 'labs_access': True}
```

I want explode permissions ignoring system_role and labs_access and having only title column from account_roles dict as rest all data is not useful.

expected data frame

```
   email          name    permissions_role_tile 
  abc@gmail.com   abc           'user'
```

I tried the following code to flatten the dataframe and drop the columns but its throwing an error `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`. Also, other posts but none of them are working.

```
df1 = (pd.concat({i: json_normalize(x) for i, x in df.pop('permissions').items()})
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .join(df)
         .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Really appreciate if I can get some help.

Comment: Can you paste the original JSON, it will be easier to flatten the whole JSON as against the dataframe

Comment: That is the original object format. Its semi structured

Comment: I guess the question is how did you get this dataframe? Where was it populated from?

Comment: Its generated in the upstream and we get a csv file in that format. And, I know that's a very bad formatting of data  ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index into the json column with the `str` method :

```
data = {"email":"abc@gmail.com", "name":"abc","permissions":[{'system_role': {'title': 'uadmin', 'mask': 64.0}, 'account_roles': [{'role': {'title': 'user', 'mask': 4}}], 'labs_access': True}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['permissions_role_title'] = df.permissions.str['account_roles'].str[0].str['role'].str['title']

       email       name          permissions             permissions_role_title
0   abc@gmail.com   abc {'system_role': {'title': 'uadmin', 'mask': 64...   user
```